# Regular expression for validating with specific characters through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to validate a string that does not allows the following characters.

```
<,>,:,","/,\,|,?,*,#
```

I want to validate this through JavaScript.
I was trying this with the following code.

```
var reg = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_]+/;
reg.test(filename[0])
```

But this was unable to validating the symbol `#`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you included the hyphen in the middle of the pattern without escaping it. This tells the engine that you are expecting a range--in this case space through underscore. It's easier (in my opinion) to place the hyphen as either the first or last character in the pattern, at which point you don't have to escape it. (It would be the second character if you are using a negated character class.)

e.g.

```
var reg = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_]+/;
```

--OR--

```
var reg = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+/;
```

--OR--

```
var reg = /[^-a-zA-Z0-9 _]+/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to allow English letters a-z (and A-Z), numbers, the space, '_', and '-'?  If so, that is different than disallowing the characters you specified since '☃' doesn't have the characters you provided but may not be a valid string in your use case.

In the case you just want the English alphabet, numbers, space, '_', and '-', you can use the following [RegExp](http://www.javascripture.com/RegExp) and conditional:

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-_]+$/; 
if (reg.test(filename[0])) {
  // String is ok
}
```

This says everything in the string between beginning (^) and end ($) must be one or more of the allowed characters.

If you want to disallow the characters you provided in your question, you can use:

```
var reg = /[\<\>\:\,\/\\\|\?\*\#]/; 
if (!reg.test(filename[0])) {
  // String is ok
}
```

This says to search for any of the characters you've listed (they are all escaped with a `\` before them) and if you find any, the string is invalid.  So only if the test fails is the string a valid string - that's why there's a `!` before the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
string  sourceString ="something" ;
var outString = sourceString.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
```